# Clip object to path drawn using free drawing brush

Tags: fabricjs

Fabric.js 2.3.6

I'm trying to clip an object to a path drawn with the free drawing bush. The code fails to show the image inside the path and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Multiple objects could be clipped, so I can't apply the path to the canvas itself.

```
let image = new Image();
let object;
let canvas;

// canvas

canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
  backgroundColor: "lightgray",
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
  selection: false
});

canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "black";
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 2;

canvas.on("path:created", function(options) {
   clip(options.path);
});

// clip

function clip(path) {

  object.set({
    clipTo: function(ctx) {
      path.render(ctx);
    }
  });

  canvas.requestRenderAll();

}

// image

image.onload = function() {

  object = new fabric.Image(image, {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    top: 50,
    left: 50
  });

  canvas.add(object);

};

image.src = "http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o91rv38q/7/

Answer (score 2):

In order to clip on the same spot when is path has been drawn, you need to reset `pathOffset` for a SVG path, and `setTransform` to the `ctx`. Your clip function will look like:

```
function clip(path) {
    path.set({pathOffset: {x: 0, y: 0}});
  object.set({
    clipTo: function(ctx) {
        ctx.save();    
      ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        ctx.beginPath();
        path._renderPathCommands(ctx);
        ctx.restore();
    }
  });

  canvas.requestRenderAll();

}
```

`_renderPathCommands` - renders a path.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o91rv38q/32/)

To clip multiple objects you'll need to have some sort of an array of objects and then combine then into single `path`:

```
function combinePaths (paths) {
  if (!paths.length) {
    return null;
  }
    let singlePath = paths[0].path;
  for (let i = 1; i < paths.length; i++){
        singlePath = [...singlePath, ...paths[i].path];
  } 
  return new fabric.Path(singlePath, {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    pathOffset: {
        x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  });
}
```

Here is an example with multiple paths to clip:

```js
// canvas

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
    backgroundColor: "lightgray",
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    preserveObjectStacking: true,
    selection: false
});

let paths = [];

canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "black";
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 2;

canvas.on("path:created", function (options) {
    paths.push(options.path);
    clip(combinePaths(paths));
});

function combinePaths(paths) {
    if (!paths.length) {
        return null;
    }
    let singlePath = paths[0].path;
    for (let i = 1; i < paths.length; i++) {
        singlePath = [...singlePath, ...paths[i].path];
    }
    return new fabric.Path(singlePath, {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        pathOffset: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
    });
}

function clip(path) {
    if (!path) {
        return;
    }
    object.set({
        clipTo: function (ctx) {
            var retina = this.canvas.getRetinaScaling();
            ctx.save();
            ctx.setTransform(retina, 0, 0, retina, 0, 0);
            ctx.beginPath();
            path._renderPathCommands(ctx);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    });

    canvas.requestRenderAll();

}

// image

let image = new Image();
let object;

image.onload = function () {

    object = new fabric.Image(image, {
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        top: 50,
        left: 50
    });
    object.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
    canvas.add(object);

};

image.src = "http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg";
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>
```

Comment: in your fiddle you added `options.path.set({top: 0});` what is the purpose of that?

Comment: It was my testing. I forgot to remove it. I updated a fiddle.

Comment: It is not working. The mask is not correctly placed. Do you know why?

Comment: In your original code it places on a different spot as well.

Comment: Yes, and I don't know why it is not working, that is why I opened a bounty.

Comment: The drawn path and the image crop still does not match. Thank you anyway.

Comment: What machine are you using for testing? It's matching for me.

Comment: MacOS Chrome last versions. The drawn path and the cropped area have different sizes and do not appear in the same place. I want to be able to precisely crop the pug nose.

Comment: Now it seems perfect. Thank you very much for your commitment in helping me solve this.

Comment: No problem. It's a nice experience.

Comment: @Observer any ideas about moving the path together with the object? I'm trying to use the top left x y but not sure how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180956/discussion-between-observer-and-lolol).